# routes.php and whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: php, laravel

I just started learning laravel and in the tutorial I found, it told me to edit the routes.php file, but when I replace the code in the file with new code I get the message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." Also in the video the routes.php file is located in the Http folder, but I don't have this folder in my directories. Instead routes.php is located in the app folder. Is this supposed to be the same fil

If I replace the following code in routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

with this code:

```
<?php
get('songs', 'SongsController@index');'
```

I get the whoops error.

Also in the video the routes.php file is located in the Http folder, but I don't have this folder in my directories. Instead routes.php is located in the app folder. Is this supposed to be the same file?

[image]

I've been stuck on this for a couple days now so any help is appreciated.
Screenshot attached of my app's directories/file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Laravel 4.2 and this tutorial that you found is using Laravel 5, that's the problem.

The `get()` helper is new to Laravel 5, so you might want to use it to follow up your tutorial.
Also, even though "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." (and it's relative package) is removed from Laravel 5, this is your error "tracking" page, so try to read the real error, it will provide more guidance on what is wrong.